# why does the toString method shows error?

Tags: java, exception, string-conversion

This is my code. I have overridden the `toString()` method. So, when an object `e` is being printed the overridden method must be called. But I don't see the method being called.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
            String name="foo";
            int a =Integer.parseInt(name);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "err";
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything that would invoke **your** `toString()`. Is that your full code?

Comment: This code makes no sense. What are you trying to do? I suggest you get a Java book and most importantly: read it.

Comment: The overridden `toString` applies to _your_ class, not `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden `toString` on whatever class you have made.  But writing `System.out.println(e);` will implicitly invoke the `toString` method on the `NumberFormatException` class, not on your class.

Why are you attempting to override `toString` on `NumberFormatException`, anyway?  What's wrong with `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` or even `e.printStackTrace();`?

Comment: i just wanted to know when and where will the toString() method be called.my trainer confused me.thanks for your answer. i used getMessage() and printStackTrace() and got fine results @rgettman